# Python how to break up a large class / generic class code structure

Tags: python, oop, code-structure

First off, I'm sure this has been asked before, but I lack the vocabulary to properly find the answer I'm looking for.  Sorry for the newbie question, and thanks for the help in advance.

So I'm creating a python test web application abstraction layer for use in test cases down the road.  The problem that I'm running into is that the web application I'm testing is HUGE, and my class is growing out of control.  So far the code I've created works like this...

```
app = ApplicationUi(browser=Chrome)
app.login(USER, PASS)
app.menu_network_settings()
app.network_dns3("192.168.1.1")
app.network_save()
app.menu_user_settings()
app.user_change_password(USER, PASS)
app.logout()
```

So everything works fine,  I'm plugging away at defining all of the methods, and things are going kinda smoothly.  The problem that I'm concerned about is there are literally thousands of elements in this configuration application, and I'd like to break it up into smaller files.  I'm not really what would be the best way to do it however.  For example here is a bit of code structure that I have.

```
class ApplicationUi(object):

    def __init__(self, url, browser="chrome"):

        display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 1920))
        display.start()
        self.driver = _driver_init(browser)
        self.driver.set_window_size(1366, 1920)
        self.driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(BASE_SLEEP)

    def __del__(self):
        if "driver" in self.__dict__.keys():
            self.driver.close()

    def logon(self, user, passwd):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="userName"]').send_keys(user)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(passwd)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="buttonid"]').click()
        time.sleep(BASE_SLEEP)

    def menu_audit(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="toolsMenu"]/span').click()
        time.sleep(BASE_SLEEP)

    def menu_resources(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PrimaryNavigationCollapse"]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[1]').click()
        time.sleep(BASE_SLEEP)

    def menu_notifications(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PrimaryNavigationCollapse"]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[2]').click()
        time.sleep(BASE_SLEEP)

    def menu_audit(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PrimaryNavigationCollapse"]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[3]').click()
        time.sleep(BASE_SLEEP)

    def menu_network(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PrimaryNavigationCollapse"]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[4]').click()
        time.sleep(BASE_SLEEP)

    def menu_emailer(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PrimaryNavigationCollapse"]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[5]').click()
        time.sleep(BASE_SLEEP)
```

So the question is what would be the best way move the menu, and network sections to their own files?

I realize I could have a base class that just had the driver initialization and login, and have a subclass for each other section, but that would change my user code to something like this

```
net = NetworkPage(BROWSER, USER, PASS)
net.dns3("192.168.1.1")
net.save()
users = UsersPage(BROWSER, USER, PASS)
users.change_password(user, password)
```

I'd like to preserve the way it's used if at all possible, but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

I also realize that I could switch it to a module, and this would allow for the structure I want,  but then (I think) I wouldn't be able to instantiate it multiple times (for simulating multiple user connections).

Thanks again.

Comment: Refactor; many of your `menu_*` methods differ *only* in the `li` index; they could be collapsed into a single method `menu_foo(x): self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="PrimaryNavigationCollapse"]/ul/li[2]/ul/li[1]/ul/li[x]').click()`.

Comment: Sure,  I could refactor the menu (and I probably will -- thanks for the pointer),  and I could have one function per page that just took all of the vars as inputs... but I'm not sure it answers the question of how to break up source into small consumable chunks

Comment: Because [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) helps. Once you stop repeating yourself, it should be clear how you can factor your code into "smaller, consumable pieces".

Comment: Well -- not to repeat myself -- I'll refactor the code and see where I end up.  If I'm still too big I guess I can always create page objects and import the methods into the main object with something like         for entry in dir(page_object):
            if callable(getattr(page_object, entry)):
                self.__dict__[entry] = (getattr(page_object, entry))